# Identify old component

Tags: identification, components, vintage

I am reverse engineering a circuit board from the early 1970s. Ford FoMoCo/Philco design. It has a metal box with six terminals. Any ideas what this is?

It measures 42x30x19mm.
The ground terminal is marked with a yellow box.
It appears the box is sealed with resin so I can't open it without completely destroying it. As this board works I don't want to damage it.

Thanks!

**UPDATE - I have measured the resistance, capacitance and inductance between all of the pins and I have added a diagram representing the results.**

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: try measuring the pins with a multimeter.

Comment: More info please. What is the whole board doing actually? There are some black wires nearby. Are these directly connected to the questioned component?

Comment: @datenheim - cruse control. One black wire is ground and is connected to the pin marked with a yellow box. I have not completed reverse engineering the board yet so I cannot tell you how the other wires relate.

Comment: @user150402 Can I see Q8 and C7 marked on the PCB? Is there a similar marking near the mystery component? Q is for transistors, C is for capacitors, so if there is some other letter (or letters) next to it that could give away what it is. A photo from directly above it would let us see too.

Comment: @AndrewMorton there are no markings on the PCB for this metal box, but that is a good idea - desoldering it just to see if there are markings underneath.

Comment: It looks like an old vibrator to me. That was used in conjunction with a transformer to generate the plate voltage for the vacuum tubes.

Comment: @gil that is interesting. I believe this circuit needs to generate pulses and it is entirely analog. I will research this.

Comment: you could ask at https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/

Comment: https://www.benzworld.org/threads/r107-cruise-control-amplifier-early-series-ford-philco.2888521/

Comment: Can you add a photo of the whole board?

Comment: @NaturalDemon Done - diagram added

Comment: @AndrewMorton I removed it from the board and the only markings were underneath "1RW/CG" and "C". They could just be related to the entire board somehow - a part number - rather than this mystery component.

Comment: @HandyHowie See the link bruce-abbot gave in his comment.

Comment: @Gil I measured the inductance of the pins - nothing. So there is no coil inside the device. In addition there are no inductors on the board except for reed relays. Is it possible it is still a vibrator?

Comment: @andya How far have you got creating a circuit diagram for the board? Given the rest of the circuit, someone might be able to see what the mystery component is likely to be.

Comment: There were electronic replacements for them when the transistors started getting available. That is just a guess, It has been since about the late 50's early 60's since I saw them.